# How to link the button to fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

Hello everyone i just want to know whether i can link the button to the Fragment class using intent .

I linked the same way how we do for Activity class using intent as shown below but now my app is crashing when i press the button.

VideoFragment is a class which extends the class to fragment (not to an Activity)

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),VideoFragment.class)); 
                    }});
```

Can anyone please help me how to link a particular fragment to the button.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you want to do? do you want to call a fragment on button click?

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya consider that there are 9 fragments embedded in one Activity and in that 1 fragment is VideoFragment.java and i have to link that Fragment

Answer (score 0):

No you have to start your activity which embeds your fragment.

If you want to replace fragment dynamically,
Here is an [example](http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/) to replace one fragment with another.

Comment: how pal can u tell how to link it@maddy